# Python NLP dependency parser from spacy library not working well

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

When I give spacy parser the sentence: "A man has been walking down the street", it says that 'been' is the root, while walking is xcompl, like 'walking' would be in the sentence: "A man loves walking down the street". Which is wrong.

Now, this doesn't happen in displacy (https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=a%20man%20has%20been%20walking%20in%20the%20street&model=en&cpu=0&cph=0). 
Does anyone know how to download the model version that displacy uses? I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this could be due to a difference in models that pip installed Spacy, and displacy use.

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> parsed = nlp("a man has been walking in the street")
>>> [(x.text,x.dep_,x.pos) for x in parsed]
[(u'a', u'det', 88), (u'man', u'nsubj', 90), (u'has', u'aux', 98), (u'been', u'ROOT', 98), (u'walking', u'xcomp', 98), (u'in', u'prep', 83), (u'the', u'det', 88), (u'street', u'pobj', 90)]
>>> nlp.meta
{u'lang': u'en', u'name': u'core_web_sm', u'license': u'CC BY-SA 3.0', u'author': u'Explosion AI', u'url': u'https://explosion.ai', u'version': u'1.2.0', u'spacy_version': u'>=1.7.0,<2.0.0', u'email': u'contact@explosion.ai', u'description': u'Small English model for spaCy. Includes vocabulary, syntax, entities and word vectors (GloVe).'}
```

Displacy model might be from one of more extensive ones listed here:

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models

core_web_sm is lightweight, displacy might be using en_core_web_md